# Draggable control in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, drag-and-drop

I'm kind of new to WPF although I have some experience in Forms, and I decided to finally try to figure out how to use WPF. So When I got to draggable controls, this is the code I came up with (I attempted to change it to work with WPF but the control just twitches everywhere):

```
private void rectangle1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed) {
        double x = this.Left + (double)e.GetPosition(this).X - (double)rectangle1.Margin.Left;
        double y = this.Top + (double)e.GetPosition(this).Y - (double)rectangle1.Margin.Top;
        rectangle1.Margin = new Thickness(x, y, rectangle1.Margin.Right, rectangle1.Margin.Bottom);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use [adorners](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743737.aspx) to achieve dragging, resizing, rotating, etc.

Comment: i really want to write the code out of scratch like only use basic stuff like events and margins etc

Comment: That's really not a smart idea when it comes to dragging controls, which is a pretty "non-trivial" task. Otherwise WPF wouldn't have introduced to concept of adorners to begin with :)

Comment: adorners really are the way to go

Answer (score 4):

Alternative:

1. Install NuGet package: `Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf`
2. Add this to root element:

```xml
xmlns:behaviors="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
```

3. And just place this inside your element:

```xml
<Grid>
    <behaviors:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <behaviors:MouseDragElementBehavior ConstrainToParentBounds="True"/>
    </behaviors:Interaction.Behaviors>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Drag works fine, but it doesn't gives any option to set any payload for the dragged control.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it by hands use following algorithm:

1. On  `MouseDown` event: Save *Mouse position*, *TopLeft position* of control, and delta(offset) of these coordinates, and set some boolean field flag eg. `IsDragStartted` to true.
2. On `MouseMove` check that drag started and use *Mouse position* and offset to calculate the new value of *TopLeft position* of control
3. On `MouseUp` event set `IsDragStartted` to false

Answer (score 2):

[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/drag-and-drop-overview) is a pretty good article on the matter on MSDN.  also, a quick search on Google revealse a veritable cornucopia of choices for you DnD dining pleasure.