# How do I make draggable controls in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, draggable

I am trying to find a way to create custom controls which lets the user drag them around on screen. This illustration shows roughly what I'm after:
[image]

So, this is basically a node network, where each node can have an arbitrary number of children and exactly one parent node. The connections between the nodes also has to follow them when they move, and bend appropriatly. I would also like all nodes to move when dragging the "canvas" behind them.

I know this is a lot of information, but basically I'm wondering if this is possible (and not too difficult) to achieve with WPF, and if it breaks with the philosophy of WPF to use it in this way. Is there a better way than using WPF for this? I've done a lot of research and can't find much info doing these things with it. Also, what is the most common ways to do this in Windows applications using .NET and C# if this seems way off?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dragable control in WPF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10022605/dragable-control-in-wpf)

Comment: I did read that post, but felt there were a lot of things not answered there that I had questions about and asked here.

Comment: the adorner link on MSDN is pretty good example of usage of adorners, which you should look into if you want to implement this in a nice manner

Comment: Start with [Thumb control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.thumb(v=vs.110).aspx) -> _Represents a control that can be dragged by the user._

Comment: Thank you for great feedback. I didn't know about the Thumb control. Is there any neat way to create something like the node connectors I described? Similar to a bezier curve with to attachment points.